# How can I post a checkbox value to a controller that saves value to session?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, session

I have the following code on checkbox click to get the checkbox value of the checkbox `showHideDeletedRps` and pass true or false to a controller `var rpInfo = await rpService.GetRPByID(id, showDeleted);`, I tried the following but it doesn't keep the selected value or doesn't update on checkbox change.

How can I apply the same logic using session?

```
@{
    var showDeleted = true; 
    if (Context.Request.HasFormContentType && Context.Request.Form.TryGetValue("showHideDeletedRps", out var formValue)
        && bool.TryParse(formValue, out var parsedFormValue))
    {
        showDeleted = parsedFormValue;
    }
    else if (Context.Request.Query.TryGetValue("showHideDeletedRps", out var queryValue)
        && bool.TryParse(queryValue, out var parsedQueryValue))
    {
        showDeleted = parsedQueryValue;
    }
 var id = Model.ID;
 var rpInfo = await rpService.GetRPByID(id, showDeleted);// used dependency injection to populate fields in a View Component 
}
```

I used this javascript code to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select[autopostback=true],input[type=checkbox][autopostback=true],input[type=radio][autopostback=true]").on("change", function () {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
</script>
```

On-change checkbox

```
<input autopostback="true" name="showHideDeletedRps" id="showHideDeletedRps" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

Comment: You can easily achieve this with AJAX. Do you mind a snippet?

Comment: @Borntocode Thank you how can i do that, i used dependency injection can i call api controller directly?

Comment: Yes you can.
Sorry I got this late. Check out @Yongqing Yu answer. I think it solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to pass the value of the checkbox to a certain action of the controller when the checkbox is clicked, you can directly achieve it by the form to complete:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
} 
<form asp-action="test" method="post">
    <input autopostback="true" name="showHideDeletedRps" id="showHideDeletedRps" type="checkbox" value="true">
</form>
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if ('@ViewData["isChecked"]' == "True") {
            $('#showHideDeletedRps').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('#showHideDeletedRps').prop('checked', false);
        }
        $("select[autopostback=true],input[type=checkbox][autopostback=true],input[type=radio][autopostback=true]").on("change", function () {
            $(this).closest("form").submit();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test(bool showHideDeletedRps)
    {
        ViewData["isChecked"] = showHideDeletedRps;
        return View();
    }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]